# How to put an arrow above a letter?

Tags: notation, vectors

Can anyone help me put $\rightharpoonup$ above $C_3$ in latex? Need to do so to indicate line integral for Green's Theorem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question should have been asked on [TeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I will bare that in mind for next time, thank you.

Comment: `\vec{C_3}` gives a slightly different but more common symbol: $\vec{C_3}$

Comment: This question has been answered in the TeX StackExchange: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96141/how-can-i-make-an-overset-symbol-at-the-same-size-and-height-as-bar-except-with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work: $\overset{\rightharpoonup}{C_3}$?

The code is: `\overset{\rightharpoonup}{C_3}`

Comment: Or `\overset{\rightharpoonup}{C}_3` if one would prefer $\overset{\rightharpoonup}{C}_3$.

Comment: ImNotThereRightNow_, thank you, that has worked. Stand by for marked as correct answer.